# javascript error uncaught syntax error in wordpress

Tags: javascript, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to add a string to variable in a Wordpress template and getting the following error. The selvalue part is working ok and setting the value in textbox as long as toto is not used in the code.

**Code with problem**

```
function run() {
    $selvalue = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
    $toto = "][3d-flip-book]";
    $flipbook_popup = "[3d-flip-book id=" + $selvalue + $toto;
    document.getElementById("srt").value = $flipbook_popup;
 }
```

**Code which works ok**

```
function run() {
    $selvalue = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
    $flipbook_popup = "[3d-flip-book id=" + $selvalue ;
    document.getElementById("srt").value = $flipbook_popup;
}
```

**Problem**
The problem is that the defining of $toto gives the following error "Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier". I have tried with escape \ for the special characters, whence it gives an error that $toto is not defined.

**Full code**

```js
function run() {
  $selvalue = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
  document.getElementById("srt").value = `[3d-flip-book id=${$selvalue}][3d-flip-book]`;
}
```

```html
<select id="Ultra" onchange="run()">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="16">text1</option>
  <option value="17">text2</option>
  <option value="18">text3</option>
</select><br><br> TextBox1
<br>
<input type="text" id="srt" placeholder="get value on option select"><br>
```

Comment: You have an extra backtick at the end of the 2nd-to-last line. ```$flipbook_popup;` ```

Comment: Thanks. It got added when I was posting the code. Edited and removed it

Comment: `document.getElementById("srt").value = \`[3d-flip-book id=${$selvalue}][3d-flip-book]\``

Comment: When you get a syntax error, it should show you exactly where it happens. Which line is it happening on?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error when I copy and paste your code.

Comment: @mplungjan  Now it gives "Uncaught SyntaxError: `` literal not terminated before end of script"

Comment: Are you sure you have backticks at the beginning and end of the value?

Comment: yes. The error on my original code points to $toto. but with the single line code, it gives literal not defined error

Comment: The string is `\`[3d-flip-book id=${$selvalue}][3d-flip-book]\`` INCLUDING the backticks. toto is not needed here

Complete script: `const $selvalue = document.getElementById("Ultra").value; document.getElementById("srt").value = \`[3d-flip-book id=${$selvalue}][3d-flip-book]\`;`

Comment: Replaced the code with your code. Now while loading the page the error did not appear. But when I have selected a value in dropdown, the error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: run is not defined"

Comment: Works in the snippet I made you

Comment: Just delete the question. It is a very specific error due to mostly typos.

Comment: I was able to decode further. The shortcode is getting expanded automatically and when it is built, it has many quotes and thereby giving all these errors. Now I have to see how to call the do_shortcode from javascript.